# How can I fix a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash in QuartzCore CALayerGetLayer, on iOS 9.3.1?

Tags: ios, swift, crash, exc-bad-access

I'm looking into a crash report in Fabric, and I have no idea what might have caused it. The stack trace is not particularly helpful, however it looks the app was preparing to be suspended in the background. Here is the crash message:

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
>
> EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x444444444444445

Here's the stack trace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  QuartzCore                     0x18680fdf0 CALayerGetLayer + 12
1  QuartzCore                     0x186810540 CA::Context::invalidate() + 68
2  QuartzCore                     0x1868104cc -[CAContextImpl dealloc] + 64
3  UIKit                          0x188f04bc4 -[UIWindow _destroyContext] + 324
4  UIKit                          0x188f049e4 +[UIWindow _prepareWindowsForAppSuspend] + 172
5  UIKit                          0x188f0491c -[UIApplication _destroyContextsAndNotifySpringBoard] + 28
6  UIKit                          0x189124244 __102-[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 240
7  UIKit                          0x1891280f0 __65-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke2283 + 148
8  FrontBoardServices             0x1856c9fc0 -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction _finishAllRequests] + 80
9  FrontBoardServices             0x1856c9d38 -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction executeRequestsWithHandler:completionHandler:expirationHandler:] + 224
10 UIKit                          0x189127ee0 __65-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke + 272
11 UIKit                          0x1891274e0 -[UIApplication _beginSnapshotSessionForScene:withSnapshotBlock:] + 900
12 UIKit                          0x189127d7c -[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:] + 560
13 UIKit                          0x189127ad0 -[UIApplication _handleSnapshotAction:forScene:completion:] + 156
14 UIKit                          0x1891243dc __102-[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke2031 + 272
15 UIKit                          0x189123ffc __102-[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke2017 + 1040
16 UIKit                          0x189126fd8 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
17 UIKit                          0x189134990 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 92
18 UIKit                          0x188e664a4 _afterCACommitHandler + 96
19 CoreFoundation                 0x183ce07b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
20 CoreFoundation                 0x183cde554 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
21 CoreFoundation                 0x183cde984 __CFRunLoopRun + 928
22 CoreFoundation                 0x183c08d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
23 GraphicsServices               0x1854f0088 GSEventRunModal + 180
24 UIKit                          0x188eddf70 UIApplicationMain + 204
25 HDWR                           0x1000706dc main (AppDelegate.swift:37)
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x1837a68b8 (Missing)
```

Any idea how I can get to the bottom of this?

Does this seem like it might be a bug in UIKit or QuartzCore, or is it more likely to be a bug in our own code?

Answer (score 0):

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x444444444444445

i think you are using nil object which is not insalized

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, but no that's not it. Swift has a different error message for that case.

Comment: i also use the Fabric , i got the EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS error i solve this . in my case my api not response  when network not available and my my response class object nil and app get crashed